# Mobile web design: background image size

Tags: html, css, mobile

Currently working on a mobile version of a website. I have this:

```
body {
background-image : url("my_image.png");
background-repeat : no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;

}
```

The background image fills the whole device screen. Question. What size in px (width) will be best for **smartphones**? Currently thinking to go with a width for the background image of 640px. Is this ok? Any suggestion please?

Comment: `background_size` is this a typo mistake? must be `background-size`

Comment: There are a lot of different screensizes so there is not really an answer to your question.

Comment: You are asking for a good background resolution ? There is no good answer as it is Performance VS Level of detail

Comment: Typo fixed, thank you Danko! But still... What do you people use? Are there any rules on this?

Comment: @user3002057 : check my answer..you better use in that way..so you don't need to add seperate styles and it will work for all resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `background-size: cover` or `contain` is usually the best way to go.
Big backgrounds could get cropped, though, so you could set `background-position` or a different background for different screen sizes with media queries, but the above usually works fine.

---

`background-size` properties:

`cover`
Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image.

`contain`
Scale the image to the largest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area.

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Answer (score 1):

640px is the width of an iPhone, so it's one of the smallest widths. A Galaxy Note 3 for example has a width of 1080px. If you want to use an absolute image size, I would suggest to use a bigger one.

However best practice in my opinion would be to use a background image that stretches itself to match the screensize, like described in Sajad's answer.